# radius of convergence of function defined by alternated addition and multiplication

Tags: complex-analysis

Starting from $z\in\mathbb{C}$, define $r(z)$ starting from the initial value $v_{0}=0.0$ and repeat the following iteration from $1,2,\ldots$

$$v_{n+1} = \begin{cases} v_{n} + \frac{z^{n}}{n!} &\text{if } 2 \not\mid n \\
v_{n} \cdot\left(1-\frac{z^{n}}{\sinh{n}}\right) & \text{if } 2 \mid n. \end{cases} $$
until it converges (I used 40 iterations below, anything much larger and I run into overflow problems)

Is there any good analytic way of getting the radius of convergence for this process? If I had to eyeball it, I'd say $e$:

[image]

$[-3,3]\times[-3,3]$ on $\mathbb{C}$

The phase portrait was generated with [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/)

```
>>> def r(z):
...     v = 0.0
...     for n in range(1,40):
...             v = v + (z**(2*n-1))/fp.fac(2*n-1)
...             v = v * (1 - (z**(2*n))/fp.sinh(2*n))
...     return v/abs(v)
fp.cplot(lambda z: r(z), [-3,3], [-3,3], points=100000, file="iter.png", verbose=True)
```

Comment: @RossMillikan: thanks, I am not a number theorist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sinh n$ is approximately $e^n/2$ when $n$ is large. So if $|z|>e$, then eventually you are multiplying by huge numbers every even step. That explains the divergence for $|z|>e$ (since the odd steps are adding a total contribution that is bounded for any given $z$).

Similarly, when $|z|<e$, eventally every even step is just multiplying by a number exponentially close to $1$. So that explains the convergence when $|z|<e$.